# jump into nearest date in a row if date entered not exist

Tags: vba, excel

my code is to find start and end date entered by user in the excel sheet so that user can find the number of product conversion for the period of entered date. it works okay if the user entered the start and end date that exist in the row. the problem is when user enter start and end date that doesn't exist in the row,it will give the number of product conversion=0. for example, my data consist of date from 1/2/2013 to 1/28/2013 with 10 product conversion. but when the user enter start date= 1/1/2013, end date= 1/29/2013 (date which not exist in the row), the number of conversion is 0. what i want to do is if the date is not exist in the row, the program will jump to the nearest date automatically.
here's my code :

```
Dim rowFound As Variant
Dim startDate As String, endDate As String, startDateRow As Long
Dim endDateRow As Long, product As String, convNo As Long

Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Products Conversion")
Set wsMain = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main Menu")

ws2.Activate
lastrow2 = ws2.Range(Range("A1"), Range("A65535").End(xlUp)).count ' find lastrow
wsMain.Activate

startDate = Me.txtStartDate.Value

endDate = Me.txtEndDate.Value

On Error Resume Next
If txtStartDate <> "" Or txtEndDate <> "" Then

For i = 3 To lastrow2

    If CDate(startDate) = ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
        startDateRow = i   ' row where start date is
        Exit For
    End If

Next


For j = lastrow2 To 3 Step -1

    If CDate(endDate) = ws2.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
        endDateRow = j      ' row where end date is
        Exit For
    End If

Next

For k = startDateRow To endDateRow - 1

    product = ws2.Cells(k, 6).Value

    If product <> ws2.Cells(k + 1, 6).Value Then
        convNo = convNo + 1 'number of conversion
    End If

Next

Else
MsgBox "Please enter both date!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
End If

Me.txtConvNo.Value = convNo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well finally i could figure it.just add some loops

```
Dim rowFound As Variant
Dim startDate As String, endDate As String, startDateRow As Long
Dim endDateRow As Long, product As String, convNo As Long

Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Products Conversion")
Set wsMain = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main Menu")

ws2.Activate
lastrow2 = ws2.Range(Range("A1"), Range("A65535").End(xlUp)).count ' find lastrow
wsMain.Activate

startDate = Me.txtStartDate.Value

endDate = Me.txtEndDate.Value

On Error Resume Next
If txtStartDate <> "" Or txtEndDate <> "" Then

resume1:
For i = 3 To lastrow2

    If CDate(startDate) = ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
        startDateRow = i ' row where start date is
        Exit For
    End If

Next

If startDateRow = 0 Then 'date entered not found in the row
    startDate = CDate(startDate) + 1
    GoTo resume1
End If

resume2:
For j = lastrow2 To 3 Step -1

    If CDate(endDate) = ws2.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
        endDateRow = j ' row where end date is
        Exit For
    End If


Next 

If endDateRow = 0 Then 'date entered not found in the row
    endDate = CDate(endDate) - 1
    GoTo resume2
End If

Next

For k = startDateRow To endDateRow - 1

product = ws2.Cells(k, 6).Value

If product <> ws2.Cells(k + 1, 6).Value Then
    convNo = convNo + 1 'number of conversion
End If

Next

Else
MsgBox "Please enter both date!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
End If

Me.txtConvNo.Value = convNo
vba excel-vba
```